# Size of a molecule

Tags: physical-chemistry

Would Aluminum Sulfate (Al2[SO4]3) pass through Whattman's paper Grade 2, which has a pore size of 8 micrometers? What is the size of an aluminum sulfate molecule, if it is possible to calculate?

Comment: Aluminum sulfate is an ionic salt, not comprised of molecules, and its constituent ions are far smaller than 8 microns.

Comment: Nearly every molecule is way smaller than 8 micrometers. Think closer to 8 micro-micrometers. It's like asking whether grains of sand can fit in a football stadium.